# Open Source command line tool for optimizing PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, open-source, optimization

Are there any open-source command line tool for optimizing PDF in Ubuntu. I have used Ghost Script and i am able to convert the PDF into 72 dpi,

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=myOutput.pdf myInput.pdf
```

But what i would like to do is mention what dpi i want to convert the PDF to, like a 300 dpi PDF file to 90 dpi PDF file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question since optimizing pdfs might be confused with linearizing them which is not what you're asking for.

Comment: Please [see this related Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280312/gui-program-to-resize-pdf-documents-and-change-their-dpi) for a number of GUI tools that can help you with optimizing your PDF files.

Answer (score 9):

I'll quote zweifel's comment on http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphowto-reduce-adobe-acrobat-file-size-from-command-line.html:

> - `dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` (screen-view-only quality, 72 dpi images)
> - `dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` (low quality, 150 dpi images)
> - `dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` (high quality, 300 dpi images)
> - `dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` (high quality, color preserving, 300 dpi
>     imgs)
> - `dPDFSETTINGS=/default` (almost identical to /screen)
>
> More options and fine tunning on the site:
>   http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/

Thus you should use either the option `dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` or the option `dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` to get 300 dpi.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not replace multiple instances of the same graphic with a single reference.