# Error when running script ('compress-pdf') in Thunar custom actions

Tags: scripts, xfce, pdf, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

I want to add [the script 'compress-pdf'](https://launchpad.net/compress-pdf) to Thunar custom actions.

The script is the one posted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/280406/47206), made to resize pdfs. It is based on `zenity`.

It was made for Nautilus, but, as stated there, it '*does not depend on any custom Nautilus variables and can be used with pretty much any file manager out there that supports custom menu actions*.'

I have added the script into a text file, made it executable, and added the path to it into Thunar custom actions with the name 'resize pdf'.

[image]

But, when right-clicking the selected pdf and running 'resize pdf', I get this error:

[image]

Why is that and how to fix it?

(Maybe the zenity script needs indeed adjustment to work in Thunar custom actions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on line 150

```
if [ -z "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
```

The variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` does not exist. You need to replace it by `pdf_file` defined on line 140.

New line 150:

```
if [ -z "$pdf_file" ]; then
```

---

The adjusted version of the script can be found **[here](http://pastebin.com/eEWHCwK7)**.